# Is this line of code a function?

Tags: php, function, oop

I got this line of code: `$user->create_account($username, $password);`.
What it does is taking username and password and create a new user, but my question isn't exactly about that. If I was calling a function, I would have done only:

```
create_account($username, $password);
```

so what does the "`->`" means? Is that actually a function?

Forgive me for the dumb question, but i have never seen something like that in an year of php.
If it was Jquery it would have been ok but it's not.

Comment: The `$user` is an object and the `create_account` is the method corresponds to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` means that you are calling a *method* from an *object*. One object is just one instance of a class and a class is just a definition of a type. Classes are the fundamental building blocks of Object Oriented Programming. When you create a class you are abstracting a concept: defining what some concept is in your application.

This definition contains both behaviors and properties. For instance, when you create a class user, one possible behavior of users is to create a new account and one possible property is the username.

In PHP behaviors are implemented as functions inside objects. Just to make distinction clear from functions outside objects we call those special functions *methods*. So when you define a class user inside of it you create a function `create_account` which represents the behavior of the user in creating one account in the system.

When you have a class `User` in php you create objects of this class (variables of type `User`) by the following syntax `$user = new User();` and some parameters can be passed to construct the object (read about constructors). Then, having the object `$user` you can access its behaviors and properties by the `->` syntax.

In that case, `$user->create_account($username, $password)` calls the method `create_account` of the `User` type passing the right parameters.

Comment: I guess the answer with the most text won. ;)

Comment: It's not about the amount of text. It's the quality of text. I understand php a lot better after reading this, and it will increase the level of my coding by quite a bit. Thank you, user1620696!

Comment: Sorry @HeinA.Grønnestad, but I understood better from what user1620696 said than you. Knowing and explaining are two different tasks and it's hard to find somebody that's good in both of them at the same time

Comment: Just trolling man, you accept the answer that helped you the most. :)

Answer (score 3):

In this case `$user` is an instance of a class (an `object`) that has a `method` called `create_account` defined. So you're calling the `create_account` method on the `$user` object.

**Example:**

```
class User {
    function create_account($username, $password) {
        // Create the account
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->create_account($username, $password);
```

This is a quick example of how the `User` class could be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?
$user is an object, and create_account() a method (=function) of this object.

Answer (score 1):

means "create_account" function belong to $user object from class you created

Answer (score 1):

`create_account` *is* a <kbd>function</kbd>, but it would be more proper to call it a <kbd>method</kbd>.  `$user` is an <kbd>object</kbd> with method `create_account`.  `->` is the accessor operator within PHP.  It is used to access an object's public methods and properties.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php.